# Angular how to get headers value in the canActive function?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I need to redirect into different user page depends on the userRole value received from the header.

**angular.routing.ts**

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full',  redirectTo: '/login' },
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { roles: Role.User} },
{ path: 'admin', loadChildren: './somemodule#SomeModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard], data: { roles: Role.Admin}},
{ path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [RandomGuard] }
```

Initially I'm redirecting into LoginComponent, 
CanActive random.guard.ts is a API call to get the header details from server.

**random.guard.ts**

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.loginService.isHeader().pipe(
        map(e => {
            // the problem is e.headers.get('userRole') undefined
            if (e.headers.get('userRole') === 'user') {
                this.router.navigate(['/user']);
            } else if(e.headers.get('userRole') === 'admin') {
                this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
            } else { 
                return true;
            }
        }),
        catchError((err) => {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return of(false);
        })
    );
}
```

**loginservice.ts**

```
isHeader(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}home/login`,{observe: 'response'}).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
            return response; 
            // response i did't get header value 
            // how to receive header value on here
        })
    );
}
```

If i subscribe the http get call, i will get the header value. How to refactor the code and recieve he header value.

Comment: Why does that info has to be inside the header? Can't it be part of the response? BTW you can actually use the HTTP interceptor to get access to the headers.

Comment: I'm just start to develop the App, i;m not using interceptors right now. If i use interceptors will fix this issue?

Comment: @Rijo Yep. Instead of getting user role in header, just return it as response.

Comment: The application first communicate BE through this API call. When I trigger this API call it will pass throuh the springboot filter service. filter servcice will provide this header details. So they can't do anything for that.

Answer (score 4):

In the backend I'm using Web API CORE, look at the following API:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("admins/overview/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetOverview(int id)
{
    var item = _adminService.GetOverviewById(id);
    Response.Headers.Add("Roles","Admin,User,Editor");// Here we add the roles with its values to Header
    Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Server,Roles"); // specify the name of headers to access
    return Ok(item);
}
```

Here, I add tow headers : the  first one is `Roles` with its values and the second one in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` with the name of headers that  we want to access them in client-side that they are **Server,Roles**

By default, only the 6 CORS-safelisted response headers are exposed:

```
Cache-Control
Content-Language
Content-Type
Expires
Last-Modified
Pragma
```

Now, You can access them in Angular.

You can `observe` the full response, to do that you have to pass `observe: response` into the options parameter

try this:

```
isHeader(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}home/login`,{observe: 'response', withCredentials: true}).pipe(
        map((response: any) => {
        // Here, resp is of type HttpResponse<Sth>.
        // You can inspect its headers:
           console.log(resp.headers.get('roles')); <-- Get Value of Roles
        // And access the body directly, which is typed as MyJsonData as requested.
           console.log(resp.body.someField);
        })
    );
}
```

And finally this is the result:

```
server: Kestrel
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
roles: Admin,User,Editor
```

See this-> [HttpClient's documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

and -> [complete explanation of Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

Comment: Have u checked? `resp.headers.get('X-Custom-Header')` is undefined, we r not able to access header value at this point

Comment: @Rijo - After many hours times,I realized that in the backend
 we should specify the headers that we want to access them in the client-side such as Angular . I modified my answer

Comment: Once i will check and let u know thanks. please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609833/angular-which-component-will-invoke-or-excecute-first