# Angular which component will invoke or execute first?

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't know weather the question is correct or not? In my application have many routing component and feature modules. I want to understand `appcomponent.ts` file or routing `logincomponent.ts` which file will execute first?

Application flow FE will communicate through BE via login API call(based on the header will switch into different component). If the login is success i'm storing those details in in one global exporting object, this will inject as service into another component.

**appcomponent.ts**

```
constructor(private auth: AuthService, private user: User) {
  this.auth.login().subscribe((res)=>{ 
  this.user.userProps.userRole = resp.headers.get('userRole');
})
}
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
{ path: '', pathMatch: 'full',  redirectTo: '/login' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [RandomGuard] }
```

random.guard.ts

```
    canActivate() {
console.log(this.user.userProps); // have null value; why app component value not receiving here
        if (this.user.userProps.userRole === 'user') {
          this.router.navigate(['/user']);
        } else if (this.user.userProps.userRole === 'admin') {
          this.router.navigate(['/admin']);
        }
        return true; // So it will redirect into login
      }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
constructor(private user: User, private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    if (this.user.userProps.userRole === '' || this.user.userProps.userRole === null) {
      this.auth.login().subscribe((resp: any) => {
        console.log(resp, 'resp');
        this.user.userProps.userRole = resp.headers.get('userRole');
        if (this.user.userProps.userRole === 'admin') {
          this.router.navigate(['/admin']); //proper routing will happaning
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/user']);
        }
      }, (err) => {
        return false;
      });
    }
    }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
login(): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.baseUrl}home/login`, {observe: 'response'});
  }
```

Here my question is which component constructor will invoke first. `appcomponent` or `logincomponent`

Comment: when you run your Angular Project the AppComponent  is the first component that will be loaded

Comment: If appcomponent will load first then why appcomponent constructor will excecuting and will get the result in `canActivate() {
console.log(this.user.userProps);` but i'm not getting result here

Comment: you could have saved yourself tons of time if you used microsoft template with identity. you run a command and you get complete authorization/authentication solution in 15 sec. you are re-inventing a bicycle here.. and once customers ask - ooh but we also want "xyz" - and you realise that you will have to rewrite everything - you recall this comment and beat yourself up..

Comment: @Rijo Did you solve this issue? I think I am also running into the same issue which I am unable to figure out why appcomponent is not loading up. I have observed this when we hit the application route to some other page than the default one. Please let me know if have resolved this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually It's the `AppComponent` that loads first after application is Bootstrapped.

If you look at your `app.module.ts`, It should contain:

```
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ] // Means this gets loaded first
```

Looking at your route config, Your `AppComponent` will load first and then routing will send you to `LoginComponent`.